# jquery resizable not working after ajax update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a resizable div that has some text in it and a edit button.

On the edit button click it opens a layer with a textbox and save button so the user can edit the text.

Then the user clicks save, the layer is closed and the db updated with some ajax. The div on the parent page is also updated with some ajax.

The problem I have is that the div is no longer resizable.

I know the line of code that is doing this and why it is doing it but cant find any other solution to updating the original div without stripping out the resizable code as well.

On the 'save' button click on the layer this function is called

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.button').click(function() {
     var edit_content = $('#myFrm').find('.nicEdit-main').html();           
     var box_id = $('#myFrm').find("#box_id").val();
     var page_ref = $('#myFrm').find("#page_ref").val();
     var template_ref = $('#myFrm').find("#template_ref").val();
      $.post("update_textarea.php",
          {
            box_id:box_id, page_ref:page_ref, template_ref:template_ref, edit_content:edit_content
          },
          function(data,status){
            UpdateElementOfParent(box_id, page_ref, template_ref)           
            edit_box('hide')
          });
    });
});
```

This updates the db and the function UpdateElementOfParent() is called on the parent page

```
function UpdateElementOfParent(box_id, page_ref, template_ref) {
   var myBox = box_id;
   $.get("get_content.php", { box_id: box_id, page_ref: page_ref, template_ref:template_ref })
   .done(function(data) {                  
        $('#'+myBox).html(data);                 
    }); 
}
```

this updates the original div with the updated content from the db.

I know the  $('#'+myBox).html(data); strips out the inner html of the div and replaces it with the text and so removes the jquery resizable text but I cant find another way to update the text.

I have tried

```
$('#'+myBox).value(data);
$('#'+myBox).text(data);
$('#'+myBox).innerHTML(data);
document.getElementById('myBox').val(data);
document.getElementById('myBox').value(data);
document.getElementById('myBox').text(data);
document.getElementById('myBox').val=data;
document.getElementById('myBox').value=data;
document.getElementById('myBox').text=data;
```

None of these work.

My javascript is not too strong(as you can probably tell).

Can anyone help with a solution?

any help greatly appreciated

QUICK UPDATE

I noticed that if I use firebug inspector the div before it has any text updates is like so

```
<div id="3" class="textarea1 ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide" style="width:300px; height:300px;position:absolute; top:10px;left:0px;overflow-y: none;background-color:transparent;" name="textarea[3]">
  newtextarea
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: none;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: none;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

but once I update it (I use nicedit to format the text) the div now has a hidden ipnout within it called 'content[]'

```
<div id="3" class="textarea1 ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide" style="width:300px; height:300px;position:absolute; top:10px;left:0px;overflow-y: none;background-color:transparent;" name="textarea[3]"></div>
<br></br>
<input type="hidden" value="
  <div align="justify">
     <font face="trebuchet ms" size="2"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto.</font>
  </div>" name="contents[1]">
</input>
```

so it would seem that the structure of the div has change and the inner input would need updating. As the input does not have an id how can I update just using its name

MORE

ok I have edited the update function to this

```
function UpdateElementOfParent(box_id, page_ref, template_ref) {
var myBox = box_id;
$.get("get_content.php", { box_id: box_id, page_ref: page_ref, template_ref:template_ref })
    .done(function(data) {                            
            var updatedata=data+"<div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e' style='z-index: 90; display: none;'></div><div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s' style='z-index: 90; display: none;'></div><div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se' style='z-index: 90; display: none;'></div></div>";
('#'+myBox).html(updatedata);                                              
    }); 
}
```

now when I check the original dv in firebug with the newly updated one the structure and contents are exactly the same.

I need to reinitialise the resizable. any clues?

Comment: what is `#box_id` is it a input field or a div/span

Comment: could you not just add a set of span tags and update between those instead of the whole box

Comment: #box_id is a passed value of the original div. so the div has an id of '1' that is passed throught eh functions and into the db and back to original div-Arun P Johny the resizable div is nested in a draggable div. to add a span would be overkill and unessesary. I just want to update the text withing the div- Daniel Tillin

Comment: I have updated my answer again, the problem is that if you don't close the `value` of `input` it will render wrong like this `Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto.
" name="contents[1]">` reslting in more html errors

Comment: I agree that the issue is with the hidden input being added but this is added via nicedit and theres nothing I can do about that. Everything is running fine except the 3 divs with the resizable code within them are missing on update and thats because I update the html of $('#'+myBox) instead of just updating the inner text. That is why I have asked for a solution to updating the text in the original post. I appreciate the help you are giving me but I think we are heading off in the wrong direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dt192's suggestion and added a span inside the div and updated the span and it works great

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Not really sure what you want really to do but.</strike>

```
var oldContent = $('#'+myBox).html();  
$('#'+myBox).html(data+oldContent);
```

Will keep the old content and add the new one.

Or you can use `.append()` http://api.jquery.com/append/ depending on what you get back when updating the database

```
$('#'+myBox).append(data);
```

**UPDATE:**

From what I can see `data` retrieves a hidden input with the value of the new text. I suggest that you either change `data` to give back something else or add the `input` value to the `div` manually.

The input is also wrong. In the `input` The `value=""` should be `value=''` because you already have `"` inside of it. After that this function should place the `value` inside the right `div`.

```
function UpdateElementOfParent(box_id, page_ref, template_ref) {
   var myBox = box_id;
   $.get("get_content.php", { box_id: box_id, page_ref: page_ref, template_ref:template_ref })
   .done(function(data) {                  
        $('#'+myBox).html(data); 
        var inval = $("input[name='contents["+myBox+"]']").val();
        $("#"+myBox).html(inval).resizable();                
    }); 
}
```

The basic problem you had at start was that you forgot to reinitialize `.resizable()` on the new `div`.

Comment: no I cant use that as I dont want to add to the end of the old data, the user change change the existing data and that needs to be updated for example 'once upon a time' change be changed to 'Once Upon A Time'. appending would make it 'once upon a timeOnce Upon A Time'

Comment: Sorry, I may have understood the question wrong, what do you mean exactly by `I know the $('#'+myBox).html(data); strips out the inner html of the div and replaces it with the text and so removes the jquery resizable text but I cant find another way to update the text.`

Comment: $('#'+myBox).html(data); this removes the html of the div and replaces it with the value of 'data' but on doing this it removes all the resizable html that was in the div in the first place

Comment: You can either format `data` so that it will be like the old html or put `data` in a child of `$('#'+myBox)`. Can you post your html structure?

Comment: can you look at my update to original post and see if you can be of any help please

Comment: I edited my post. Are you allowed to change the results received from the server? It would make things so much easier to just change that.

Comment: I cannot change the result as that is created by the nicedit rich text editor, even the double quotes within double quotes if from that. I havetried out your function but it does not reinitialise the resizable